# Spark does not build in intellij due to external Flume project issues

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

I have checked out from spark snapshot-2.0.0 and built it successfully on the command line via

```
mvn clean package -Psparkr -Djavadoc.skip=true -DskipTests=true -Phadoop-2.6
-Dhadoop.version=2.7.1 -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dscala-2.11 -Phive-thriftserver
```

However doing a full rebuild in Intellij results in errors in the `flume` external module:

[image]

Is anyone else seeing this problem / or has found a workaround?